# Запрос выводит данные, несмотря на несуществующий ID

Tags: php, mysql

Страница `example.com/item/5/` выводит данные из БД на основе текущего id, в данном случае ID=5.

Запрос к БД выглядит примерно так:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_id = '".$_GET['item_id']."
```

Проблема заключается в том, что если в адрес страницы, в данном случае, к 5 добавить какие-либо буквы, то страница всё равно вызвается по id = 5.

Например, `example.com/item/5xyz/` или `example.com/item/5fldsf/` выводят страницу по ID 5.

Прошу помочь. :(

Comment: А вы передайте в качестве item_id значение `1'; DROP TABLE items;` - вообще счастливы будете ))

Если серьезно - проверяйте пришедшее значение, например, через [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.is-numeric.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такая вещь, как ["преобразование типов данных"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html).

И поскольку Вы передаете не числовое значение, а строку (обращаем внимание на скобки **' '**), то она подлежит преобразованию. Как итог, все не числовые значения справа отбрасываются, и вы получаете обычное число `'5xyz' => 5`.

Для учебы такие запросы пойдут, но в реальном приложении, если Вы не проверяете полученные значения и сразу пихаете их в запрос, то это очень большая дыра в безопасности. Посмотрите хотя бы на PDO в будущем и проверяйте значения.

Answer (score 0):

1. Проверять правильность ввода.
2. Проверять наличие данного ид в базе.
3. Если уж сильно параноик, можно еще и создавать специальные хэши для форм ввода и при передаче проверять их